# Elasticsearch match multiple IP subnets DSL Query

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to do a DSL Query filter in Kibana for a specific URI, while matching multiple IP subnets.
So far I have managed to make it work with only one IP subnet:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "uripath": "/specific-uri-path"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "clientip": "10.0.0.0/8"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But if I try to match for multiple subnets, it fails (probably because match can only contain different fields):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "uripath": "/specific-uri-path"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "clientip": "10.0.0.0/8",
          "match": {
            "clientip": "14.0.0.0/8"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Combine match using should or use multi match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with the terms query. That means that I can also use an array of values for "clientip", so overall it's cleaner. I hope it will help someone else too.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
        "uripath.keyword": "/specific-uri-path"
      }
    },
    {
      "terms": {
        "clientip": [
          "10.0.0.0/8",
          "14.0.0.0/8",
          "20.0.0.0/8"
        ]
      }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```